# Issues after customizing the Superfish drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I've been tinkering around with the excellent [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/) drop-down menu to fit my needs. [Here](http://labs.pieterdedecker.be/test/menus/example.html)'s the result. Still, there are two oddities I need to fix.

Since I changed the font family and font size used for the items in the menu bar, the drop-down menus are aligned incorrectly a few pixels lower than where they should be.

Secondly, when I hover over a menu item that has a submenu, an arrow to the right is displayed but it's not as visible as it should be due to the light background color. Can I change this quickly without making a new arrow image?

Comment: its really buggy... if i press on a tab, the drop down disapears before i can select a sub catagory... im running linux, firefox. U might wana search for better sollution than superfish

Comment: http://plugins.jquery.com/taxonomy/term/146, or http://www.noupe.com/tutorial/drop-down-menu-jquery-css.html

Comment: It appeared to be buggy because the menus weren't tied to the menu bar correctly. If you try it again, it should work. http://labs.pieterdedecker.be/test/menus/example.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, look for this section of the css, around line 34, and tweak the value of 'top' down to suit, probably down to around 1.5em:

```
.sf-menu li:hover ul, .sf-menu li.sfHover ul {
left:0;
top:2.5em;
z-index:99;
}
```

Secondly, not really.  A new image is the way to go, if you want to change the way the arrows look.